# Shimano 10 - 11 system hub compatibility - MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, drivetrain

I have Shimano XT 11 speed compatible rear wheel (on Novatec hubs, the ones that came with Kona Process 134 DL 2016). Can I use Shimano 10 speed MTB system on this hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use Shimano 10 speed MTB system on this hub?

Yes, you can, but a 2mm spacer *might* be need.

10 speed Shimano MTB cassettes require same freehub body width as 11 speed. Meanwhile, Shimano road-specific cassettes are ~2mm wider. To be sure, I'd measure freehub body width ([36.75 on that pic](https://www.bikerumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/DT-Swiss-Shimano-11-speed-hub-diagram3.gif)). If it's about 37mm, that means rear hub can accomodate wider 11 speed road cassettes and you will need a spacer for sure. Otherwise, you can put a 10 speed cassette as is.

On a side note, Novatec (Joytech) produces a wide variety of hubs, same models can have both XD, 10 and 11 freehub body options.